# OpenMPI multiple MPI_Send and MPI_recv not working

Tags: linux, 64-bit, centos, openmpi

When i tried to call multiple MPI_Send or MPI_Recv in the program, the executable is getting hanged in the nodes and the root. ie, when it is trying to execute the second MPI_Send or MPI_Recv, the communication is getting blocked. At the same time the binaries are running at 100% in the machines.

When i tried to run this code in windows 7 64 bit with OpenMPI 1.6.3 64-bit, it ran successfully. But the same code is not working in Linux, ie, CentOS 6.3 x86_64 with OpenMPI 1.6.3 -64 bit. What is the problem i have done.

Posting the code below

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
MPI::Init();
int rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
int size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
char name[256] = { };
int len = 0;
MPI::Get_processor_name(name, len);

printf("Hi I'm %s:%d\n", name, rank);

if (rank == 0) 
{
    while (size >= 1) 
    {
        int val, stat = 1;
        MPI::Status status;
        MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&val, 1, MPI::INT, 1, 0, status);
        int source = status.Get_source();
        printf("%s:%d received %d from %d\n", name, rank, val, source);

        MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&stat, 1, MPI::INT, 1, 2);
        printf("%s:%d sent status %d\n", name, rank, stat);

        size--;
    }
} else 
{
    int val = rank + 10;
    int stat = 0;
    printf("%s:%d sending %d...\n", name, rank, val);
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&val, 1, MPI::INT, 0, 0);
    printf("%s:%d sent %d\n", name, rank, val);

    MPI::Status status;
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&stat, 1, MPI::INT, 0, 2, status);
    int source = status.Get_source();
    printf("%s:%d received status %d from %d\n", name, rank, stat, source);
}

size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
if (rank == 0) 
{
    while (size >= 1) 
    {
        int val, stat = 1;
        MPI::Status status;

        MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&val, 1, MPI::INT, 1, 1, status);
        int source = status.Get_source();
        printf("%s:0 received %d from %d\n", name, val, source);

        size--;
    }

    printf("all workers checked in!\n");
} 
else
{
    int val = rank + 10 + 5;
    printf("%s:%d sending %d...\n", name, rank, val);
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&val, 1, MPI::INT, 0, 1);
    printf("%s:%d sent %d\n", name, rank, val);
}
MPI::Finalize();

return 0;
```

}

Hi Hristo, I have changed the source as you said and the code is again posting

```
    #include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int iNumProcess = 0, iRank = 0, iNameLen = 0, n;
    char szNodeName[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME] = {};
    MPI_Status stMPIStatus;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &iNumProcess);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &iRank);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(szNodeName, &iNameLen);

    printf("Hi I'm %s:%d\n", szNodeName, iRank);

    if (iRank == 0) 
    {
        int iNode = 1;
        while (iNumProcess > 1) 
        {
            int iVal = 0, iStat = 1;
            MPI_Recv(&iVal, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stMPIStatus);
            printf("%s:%d received %d\n", szNodeName, iRank, iVal);

            MPI_Send(&iStat, 1, MPI_INT, iNode, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("%s:%d sent Status %d\n", szNodeName, iRank, iStat);

            MPI_Recv(&iVal, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stMPIStatus);
            printf("%s:%d received %d\n", szNodeName, iRank, iVal);

            iNumProcess--;
            iNode++;
        }

        printf("all workers checked in!\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        int iVal = iRank + 10;
        int iStat = 0;
        printf("%s:%d sending %d...\n", szNodeName, iRank, iVal);
        MPI_Send(&iVal, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("%s:%d sent %d\n", szNodeName, iRank, iVal);

        MPI_Recv(&iStat, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stMPIStatus);
        printf("%s:%d received status %d\n", szNodeName, iRank, iVal);

        iVal = 20;
        printf("%s:%d sending %d...\n", szNodeName, iRank, iVal);
        MPI_Send(&iVal, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("%s:%d sent %d\n", szNodeName, iRank, iVal);

    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

i got the output as folows. ie, after the send send/receive, root is infinitely waiting and the nodes are ruing with 100% CPU utilisation. Its output is giving below

```
Hi I'm N1433:1
N1433:1 sending 11...
Hi I'm N1425:0
N1425:0 received 11
N1425:0 sent Status 1
N1433:1 sent 11
N1433:1 received status 11
N1433:1 sending 20...
```

Here N1433 and N1425 are machine names. Please help

Answer (score 3):

The code for the master is wrong. It is always sending to and awaiting messages from the same rank - rank `1`. Thus the program would only function correctly if run as `mpiexec -np 2 ...`. What you've probably wanted to do is to use `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` as the source rank and then use that source rank as the destination in the send operation. You shouldn't also use `while (size >= 1)` since rank `0` is not talking to itself and the number of communications is expected to be one less than `size`.

```cpp
if (rank == 0) 
{
    while (size > 1)
    //     ^^^^^^^^
    {
        int val, stat = 1;
        MPI::Status status;
        MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&val, 1, MPI::INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, status);
        // Use wildcard source here ------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        int source = status.Get_source();
        printf("%s:%d received %d from %d\n", name, rank, val, source);

        MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&stat, 1, MPI::INT, source, 2);
        // Send back to the same process --------^^^^^^
        printf("%s:%d sent status %d\n", name, rank, stat);

        size--;
    }
} else
```

Doing something like this in the worker is pointless:

```cpp
MPI::Status status;
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&stat, 1, MPI::INT, 0, 2, status);
// Source rank is fixed here ------------^
int source = status.Get_source();
printf("%s:%d received status %d from %d\n", name, rank, stat, source);
```

You have already specified rank `0` as the source in the receive operation so it would only be able to receive messages from rank `0`. There is no way that `status.Get_source()` would return any value other than `0`, unless some communication error had occurred, in which case an exception would get thrown by `MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv()`.

The same is also true for the second loop in your code.

By the way, your are using what used to be the official standard C++ bindings. They were deprecated in MPI-2.2 and the latest version of the standard (MPI-3.0) removed them completely as no longer supported by the MPI Forum. You should be using the C bindings instead or rely on 3-rd party C++ interfaces like `Boost.MPI`.

Comment: Hi Hristo,I have changed the source and posting below.

Answer (score 1):

After installing and MPICH2 instead of OpenMPI, it worked successfully. I think there is some problem in using OpenMPI 1.6.3 in my cluster machines.